# Should I use function pointers or polymorphism?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, function-pointers

I have a need where I want to pass an object to a class, and depending on a value in this passed object, for the class to use one of two set of methods. I don't alter b in any way in this class. I want this to be as transparent to the user as possible, so that they pass in the object, and then just call the methods as normal, so I'm trying to avoid the need to make Foo1 and Foo2 classes to be managed separately.

e.g.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(Bar & b){
            useScheme1 = b.a == 1;
        }

        void methodA(){
            // call either A1 or A2
        }

        void methodB(){
            // call either B1 or B2
        }

    protected:
        bool useScheme1 = false;
        // methods A1, A2, B1 and B2 defined as protected functions
        .
        .
        .

};
```

Comment: Without knowing the specifics, if I were posed with such a problem I would be leaning towards a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your problem well but... Why not a simple `if (useScheme1) { } else { }`?

Comment: Use polymorphism. That's what it's for.

Comment: @Holt for that, I'd have to store the instance of Bar as a local member. I don't want to do that as I make no use of it.

Comment: @user3791372: Why do you think you need the Bar as local member?

Comment: heh, you're right. K.I.S.S and all that jazz! ```if (useScheme1)...``` makes sense, and removes the need for function pointers / another solution! @Holt, put that as an answer so I can accept! Thanks

Comment: @Holt: In this case it might be ok, but if you´ve 10 possibilities ... with 10 subclasses, it´s probably easier to overview what belongs together, instead with an if-chain in each method. At least one reason against it.

Comment: @deviantfan are you suggesting that more than 2 possibilities, and a switch would be impractical and to put the methods into separate classes instead and store an instance of the desired class internally?

Comment: @deviantfan Of course, I didn't say it was a generic solution, I only gave a possible solution for this specific case.

Comment: @user3791372 No, I´m not really suggesting it. I thought more of subclasses+factory pattern, but that has it´s own problems. Probably more than advantages. And a wrapper (like you´re thinking), well na ... just use switch directly within each method :)

Answer (score 3):

This kind of functionality is *exactly* what dynamic polymorphism is for! I would absolutely suggest to use a very basic creator function and `Foo` + children, something like this:

```
namespace foo_library {

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void methodA() = 0;

    virtual void methodB() = 0;

    virtual ~Foo() {}
};

class Foo1 : public Foo
{
    virtual void methodA()
    {
        // Do A1 here.
    }

    virtual void methodB()
    {
        // Do B1 here.
    }
};

class Foo2 : public Foo
{
    virtual void methodA()
    {
        // Do A2 here.
    }

    virtual void methodB()
    {
        // Do B2 here.
    }
};

Foo* create_foo(const Bar& b)
{
    if(b.a == 1) return new Foo1;

    return new Foo2;
}
}

// Then you use it like this:
int main()
{
    Bar b; // Initialize it.
    std::unique_ptr<foo_library::Foo> foo = foo_library::create_foo(b);    // Use the appropriate smart pointer for your ownership needs.
    foo->MethodA();   // Decides which to do based on the bar.
}
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of having the create_foo function just hanging there in a global namespace. It'd be a lot nicer if Foo could just be initialised, and the Foo1/Foo2 was completely transparent to the user which a pointer only half does - right?

Comment: @user3791372 I had hoped it was obvious the code was just for illustration. There's no reason you can't put the whole thing in a namespace appropriate to your need - I'll edit in a demonstration. As for `Foo`/`Foo1`, with the create function the user never even has to know about the child classes at all.

Comment: @user3791372: You can put the create-method inside Foo as static method too.

Comment: `create_foo` should not be returning a raw pointer.  There are very few good reasons for factory functions to return raw pointers -- return `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: @Yakk I actually thought about that and decided that I'd rather give the user the flexibilty to `scope` or `share` the pointer if they wanted.

Comment: @MarkB `shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr( unique_ptr<U, Deleter >&& )` is a constructor, so returning `unique_ptr` does not block sharing.  And `.release()` is always available if you want to get back to a raw pointer anyhow (for some smart pointer without that overload).  So I maintain my case: factory methods should not return raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, using function pointers to achieve what you're trying to do is the C solution to the problem.  And you're writing code in C++, not C.  So that speaks for itself.

That said, using pointers here gives you the flexibility of making a last-minute runtime decision, perhaps based on the value of some other parameter (e.g., if you need to select which function to use and those functions could differ not so much on the basis of the object but some other runtime condition).

Aside from scenarios like the one mentioned above, I'd use polymorphism; it makes the code more transparent in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is C++11.  pImpl type erasure.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo( Bar const& b ):
    pScheme( makeScheme1(b.a==1) )
  {}
  void methodA() { pScheme->methodA(this); }
  void methodB() { pScheme->methodB(this); }
private:
  struct Scheme {
    virtual void methodA(Foo* self) const = 0;
    virtual void methodB(Foo* self) const = 0;
    virtual ~Scheme() {};
  };
  std::shared_ptr<const Scheme> pScheme;
  struct Scheme1:Scheme {
    void methodA(Foo* self) const override {
      std::cout << "Scheme1::methodA[" << self << "]\n";
    }
    void methodB(Foo* self) const override {
      std::cout << "Scheme1::methodB[" << self << "]\n";
    }
  };
  struct Scheme2:Scheme {
    void methodA(Foo* self) const override {
      std::cout << "Scheme2::methodA[0x" << self << "]\n";
    }
    void methodB(Foo* self) const override {
      std::cout << "Scheme2::methodB[0x" << self << "]\n";
    }
  };
  std::shared_ptr<const Scheme> makeScheme( bool bScheme1 ) {
    if (bScheme1) { return std::make_shared<Scheme1>(); }
    else { return std::make_shared<Scheme2>(); }
  }
};
```

Now you can construct a `Foo` based off of a `Bar`, which builds an internal `Scheme` depending on the parameters of `b`.

Within the `Scheme` I pass in a `Foo* self` so you have access to the data of `Foo`, in case you need it.

There is inheritance here, but it is an implementation detail that clients don't care about.  Your `Foo` acts like a value type, not a pointer type, which makes it easier to use.  You can even assign over a `Foo` with another `Foo` and it just works (the scheme of the source is shared).

If you want to support `Scheme`-less `Foo`, you'll need to check `pScheme` before dereferencing.  As it stands, a moved-from `Foo` is not safe to invoke `methodA` or `methodB`.